# Detect if a remote computer is Windows or Linux OS

Tags: c#, linux, wmi, solaris

I have IP Address and Server name of a remote computer. I am able to query `WMI` to get the `OS version` if the computer is running Windows but is there a way i can query the remote computer and get the `OS version` if the computer is not running Windows (`Linux`, `Solaris`)?

Comment: At the least, I am one person interested in knowing the answer to this question...

Comment: use nmap in with Command Line Arguments. That should do the trick. Something like nmap -A <IP-Address> >> somefile.txt. And then read the file to get the OS.

Comment: I am not authorized to use third party utilities.

Comment: Cross-site dup - http://superuser.com/questions/323238/how-can-i-determine-the-os-of-a-remote-computer... Maybe you should have asked on SU/SF to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `Active Directory` is going to give me what i need. This is what i have so far. Looks promising.

```
    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        ComputerPrincipal computer = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "mylinuxservername");

        if (computer != null)
        {
            var unObject = computer.GetUnderlyingObject() as System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry;
            if(null != unObject)
            {
                var osProperty = unObject.Properties.Cast<System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection>().Where(p => p.PropertyName == "operatingSystem");

                if(null != osProperty.FirstOrDefault())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(osProperty.FirstOrDefault().Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this seems to work, too: unObject.Properties["operatingSystem"].Value as string

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to detect that the remote computer is using Windows OS or Linux . Information gathering consist that part under penetration testing .
Basically after scanning number of ports on the remote computer and the running services on these ports , we can decide that what OS is installed on the remote computer.
There are one more way to check it , you can use **SNMP Protocol** for that purpose.

```
user@host $ snmpget -v2c -c <community string> <computer> <mib / oid >
```

eq.

```
user@host $ snmpget -v2c -c public x.x.x.x sysDescr.0
```

will gives you the information related to the remote computer .
By default **<community string>** is **public** .

Answer (score -1):

from your Windows PC to know what is the Windows version of the remote PC, you can run the windows command "systeminfo /s [PCname]" or you can use

Comment: Looks like the OP has Windows machines covered. The question is about non-Windows machines.

Comment: @Vince: I already know how to do it for Windows Computer. Also note that systeminfo gives too much information. All i need is OS. I got that using WMI.

Comment: without installing any software, that looks difficult. If you could install a tool (even tool that need no registry permission), you could query the SNMP MIBs or use nmap. If there is a webserver on the remote server, any web language (php. javascript...) could help you to retrieve info from the HTTP header....